# AWS ECS VPC endpoints not reachable from ecs-agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, endpoint, vpc

While deploying ECS cluster using the AWS endpoints for ECS and ECR. The ecs-agent is not able to reach https://ecs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com. I have no internet gateway, nat gateway or any proxy setup for this environment.

To debug the issue, I am logging onto the ECS host machines. A curl command to  https://vpce****/ecs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com works since it resolves directly to the network interface of the ECS endpoint.

However the generic url https://ecs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com does not resolve to anything.
I have validated that private DNS is enabled for this endpoint.

Here are my findings on the above situation.

The routing is correct and end point is setup correctly since I am able to resolve using the vpce endpoint

Private DNS option is enabled on endpoint & dns resolution enabled on vpc) but I don't see a hosted zone created for amazonaws.com in my route 53. Is this something that gets created and shown to user account or managed internally by AWS?

Please let me know some pointers on how to debug this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my VPC using custom DHCP options set. This means that the primary DNS for my VPC was pointing to on premise DNS servers which had no forwarding rules configured to resolve the private end points.
The solution to such a scenario will be to create an inbound resolver in route 53 and have a conditional forwarding rule on your on premise DNS server to forward those requests to the inbound resolver which then should be able to get the private ENI.